# python 2.7 signal value errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

Please, who can explain why I get this error :

```
ValueError: invalid signal value
```

when trying to execute this test code, under Python 2.7.6 as well as under Python 3.3

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):    
    print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)

signal.signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, handler)
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: From the [`CTRL_C_EVENT` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.CTRL_C_EVENT): *Availability: Windows.* Are you sure you are using Windows?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 starter, SP1

Answer (score 11):

You cannot register a signal handler for `CTRL_C_EVENT`, because it is not supported.

Unfortunately, the Python docs on [CTRL_C_EVENT](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)  don't really state that explicitly: When the docs say "*the signal can only be used with `os.kill`*", they mean it literally, as in "really, all you can do with this signal is use it as in `os.kill(pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)`, so don't try registering a handler for it".

For some background, see [Python issue 9524](https://bugs.python.org/issue9524).

Should the behavior be better documented? Hell yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`pywin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/):

```
import win32api

def ctrl_handler(n: int):
    print("Caught Ctrl+C")
    return True

win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrl_handler, True)
```